# Exercise 11 page 30 in Functional Analysis book of Conway

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

The following is Exercise 11 page 30 in Functional Analysis book of Conway:

> If $A = 
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         a & b \\
>         c & d  \\
>         \end{bmatrix}
> $, put $\alpha=[|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2+|d|^2]^{1/2}$ and show that $\|A\| = \frac12 (\alpha^2+\sqrt{\alpha^4-4\delta^2})$, where ${\delta}^2 = \det A^* A$.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459696/norm-of-a-2-times-2-matrix-as-a-hilbert-space-operator) some details are added but there is no satisfactory answer. Also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2735797/how-i-can-calculate-the-norm-of-this-matrix) is another link that asks the same question without an answer based on materials taught. The exercise appears at  page 30 of the book which lacks concepts like :

> The operator Euclidean norm of $A$ is just the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A^∗A$.

A detailed simple answer or a hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is $\|A\|$?

Comment: @ArcticChar, $||A||=sup{\{||Ax||, ||x||=1}\}$ for all $(x_1,x_2)^T =x \in H$ (?)

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to compute $\lVert Ax\rVert^2=\overline{(Ax)}^T(Ax)=\bar{x}^T\overline{A}^TAx$ for $2\times 2$ matrix $A$?

Comment: @user10354138, I want to prove that $||A||=\sup{\{||Ax||, ||x||=1}\}=\frac12 (\alpha^2+\sqrt{\alpha^4-4\delta^2})$

Comment: Use the Lagrange multiplier method to find the maximum of $\lVert Ax\rVert^2$ on the compact manifold $\{x_1^2+x_2^2=1\}$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, I don't know about Lagrange multipliers unfortunately that's why I couldn't reply to MaoWao.

Comment: @L.G. You don't even need Lagrange multipliers, parameterize your vector $x$ as $x = (sin(t), cos(t))$ as it has Euclidean norm $1$. Then it becomes a $1$ variable optimization problem without constraints.

Comment: @Rammus, I've tried that but would resulted in (a-b+c-d)(sint cost)=0, a far thing to the conclusion that the book has suggested!

Comment: @OliverDiaz Ahh ok, by the second comment's use of transpose I assumed things were real. One can then just add a phase parameter $(\mathrm{sin}(t), \mathrm{e}^{i s} \mathrm{cos}(t) )$ and you still have an unconstrained optimization.

Comment: @L.G. The links that you referred to, specially the second one, use results that can be proved easily with what you know about operators. If it bothers you that they come at later sections, just prove them for your homework and use them... I do suggest that you review Lagrange multipliers from your Calculus courses.

Comment: @L.G. Here is a short proof that $\|T\|^2=\|T^*T\|$ for operators in Hilbert spaces:From definition of operator norm
\begin{align*}
\|T^*\|&=\sup_{\|y\|=1}\|T^*y\|=\sup_{\|y\|=1}\sup_{\|x\|=1}|(x,T^*y)|=
\sup_{\|y\|=1}\sup_{\|x\|=1}|(Tx,y)|\\
&=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\sup_{\|y\|=1}|(Tx,y)|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|=\|T\|
\end{align*}
Therefore $T^*\in\mathcal{L}(H,H)$ and $\|T\|=\|T^*\|$. Let $x\in H$ with $\|x\|=1$. It follows from
$$\|Tx\|^2=(Tx,Tx)=(x,T^*Tx)\leq\|x\|\|T^*Tx\|\leq \|T^*T\|\leq\|T^*\|\|T\|=\|T\|^2$$
that $\|T\|^2\leq\|T^*T\|=\|T\|^2$.

Comment: @L.G. Once $\|A\|=\sqrt{\|A^*A\|}$ has been established, the rest is as in the second link in your posting.

Comment: @L.G. Notice that the matrix $A^*A$ is positive definite. By a well known result in linear algebra, there is an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $P(A^*A)P^*$ is a diagonal matrix, where the elements of the diagonal are the eigenvalues (all real and nonnegative). It follows from this, that $\|A^*A\|$ is the same as the largest eigenvalue of $A^*A$.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a typo in this exercise: the result to be proved is $\|A\|^2 = \frac12 (\alpha^2+\sqrt{\alpha^4-4\delta^2})$. Just check with  $A = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 0 \\
        0 & 2  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$.

Now, it is easy to see that
$$\|A\|^2=\sup{\{\|Ax\|^2, \|x\|=1}\} = \sup{\{\langle Ax, Ax \rangle, \|x\|=1}\} = \\ =\sup{\{\langle A^*Ax, x \rangle, \|x\|=1}\}  \tag{1}$$
Since $A^*A$ is a self-adjoint operator, it is diagonalisable, with real eigenvalues. So
$$ \sup{\{\langle A^*Ax, x \rangle, \|x\|=1}\} = \text{ the largest eigenvalue of } A^*A \tag{2}$$

Now, let us compute $A^*A$. We have
$$ A^*A =  \begin{bmatrix}
        \bar a & \bar c \\
        \bar b & \bar d  \\
        \end{bmatrix}  
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d  \\
        \end{bmatrix}= 
       \begin{bmatrix}
        |a|^2 +|c|^2 &  \bar a b + \bar c d \\ 
        a \bar b + c \bar d & |b|^2 +|d|^2  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
So, the eigenvalues of $A^*A$ will be the roots of the the equation
$$ \lambda ^2 - (|a|^2 +|c|^2  + |b|^2 +|d|^2 ) \lambda + \det(A^*A)= 0 $$

Now since we defined $\alpha^2= |a|^2 +|c|^2  + |b|^2 +|d|^2$ and $\delta^2 = \det(A^*A)$, we have that
$$ \lambda ^2 - \alpha^2 \lambda + \delta^2= 0 $$
So,
$\lambda  = \frac12 (\alpha^2\pm\sqrt{\alpha^4-4\delta^2})$. Since $A^*A$ has real eignevalues we know that $\alpha^4-4\delta^2 \geq 0$ and that the largest eigenvalue is $ \frac12 (\alpha^2 +\sqrt{\alpha^4-4\delta^2})$. So, from $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have that
$$\|A\|^2 = \frac12 (\alpha^2 +\sqrt{\alpha^4-4\delta^2})$$